# How to use a custom renderer based on request params?

Tags: django, csv, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Goal:**

Have every endpoint taking `export=csv` in the params to output a CSV file instead of Json data by using a custom Renderer and not changing every View's code

---

Setting another Renderer seemed like the simplest solution:

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, CSVRenderer)
    pagination_class = StandardPagination
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    ...
```

and on the `CSVRenderer` check if the url contains `export=csv`, but this yields plain text data in CSV format and not a file. Removing the `BrowsableAPIRenderer` would work but I still need to have the endpoint working without the `export=csv`.

Is there a way to have something checking the url before the renderers are called?

Suggestions are welcome if theres be a better way to achieve this.

---

Edit: My Renderer is a CSVRenderer from [djangorestframework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework-csv):

```
from rest_framework_csv import renderers as r

class CSVRenderer(r.CSVRenderer):
    pass
```

Edit2: `StandardPagination` is simply a `rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination`

Answer (score 0):

There is a package named [`djangorestframework-csv`](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv) that might be worth looking at. I believe it does what you are trying to achieve. It is listed under the [CSV rendering section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#csv) in the [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Edit: 
Can you please show the code for `StandardPagination`? 
Also could you please try with the GET parameter as `format` e.g. `http://<domain>/<url to view>/?format=csv`?

Edit:
I have replicated your code in the following way with the serializer and queryset being different as I don't have yours:

```
from rest_framework_csv import renderers as r
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.renderers import BrowsableAPIRenderer
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

from .. import Account, AccountSerializer


class PageNumberPagination2(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2


class CSVRenderer(r.CSVRenderer):
    pass


class MyView(ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, CSVRenderer)
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination2
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

In the `urls.py` I have added the pattern `url(r'^test/', MyView.as_view()),`. when going to `/test/` I get the browsable view and `/test/?format=csv` the CSV file.

Can you please confirm this is an equivalent setup to what you have and you have not used `format_suffix_patterns` around the URLs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My CSVRenderer is already extending the renderer from this library, but there's still the same problem, which is basically ignoring the other renderers based on the url params.

Comment: Could you please provide your extended renderer?

Comment: passing `?format=csv` weirdly returns 404. `StandardPagination` is simply a `rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination`

Comment: Very strange about the 404; `format` is the default suffix for changing the format as can be seen at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/#query-parameter-formats Did you happen to modify it to `export`?